# Controlling Path Of Handled Application_Error View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, handleerror

I have the following code which handles all execptions that occur outside of action results (where the HandleErrorAttribute cannot reach).

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        Response.Clear();

        HttpException httpException = (HttpException)exception;

        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

        if (httpException == null)
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Home");
        }
        else //It's an Http Exception, Let's handle it.
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Handle");
        }

        // Pass exception details to the target error View.
        routeData.Values.Add("error", httpException);

        // Clear the error on server.
        Server.ClearError();

        // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
        IController errorController = new SPP.Areas.UI.Controllers.ErrorController();
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
    }
```

This does the job just fine. It executes the "Handle" action on the "Error" controller just like I have set it. No problem.

When inside the action it then throws another exception which is then picked up by my HandleErrorAttribute filter. After debugging it I can clearly see it is looking for the following paths.

- ~/Views/Error/Handle.aspx
- ~/Views/Error/Handle.ascx
- ~/Views/Shared/Handle.aspx
- ~/Views/Shared/Handle.ascx
- ~/Views/Error/Handle.cshtm
- ~/Views/Error/Handle.vbhtml
- ~/Views/Shared/Handle.cshtml
- ~/Views/Shared/Handle.vbhtml

I am using the Razors view engine along with **Areas**. My reason for doing this. So I can keep my application nice a tidy. My problem is that it looks like I am being forced to create a directory within my application just so this file can sit inside it...I am not a fan of this.

I would much rather prefer it going to the following location.

- ~/Areas/UI/Views/Error/Handle.cshtml

Or something like...

- ~/Areas/Shared/Views/Error/Handle.cshtml

Now I **CAN** resolve this by creating that directory at the root of the application.

The reason I have not done this is because if I start caving in and using an easy way out approach. My applications will get very messy very quickly. I like to be the one who defines where my files and folders live.

If anyone knows of a way to set the direct path, or tell the IController (errorcontroller) to look in the Area in which it has been instanciated I will love you forever.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Steve